How to exclude certain Otel spans from being exported (programatically in Python)?
My application processes messages from rabbit queue. Lots of the messages are inappropriate for processing (not ideal, but  for a valid reason), so the application is just rejecting them upon reading without re-queuing them.
As the messaging library (aio_pika) is otel instrumented, it generates loads of unnecessary spans that are exported. What is the best way to exclude these spans from being exported?
I haven't found a way to signal this, or mark the current span as "non-recording".
I'm thinking about:
a) writing a SpanProcessor wrapper that would drop custom marked spans
b) writing custom / patching aio_pika instrumentation to support this filtering
Yet, I hope there is a better way.
I do not want to export the spans and filter them out on the Otel Collector level.
Besides the above mentioned scenario, I have other use-cases, when I'd like to exclude (declaratively or programatically) some spans from flooding the exporter/collector.
Thank you for any ideas.
